# automatic provisioning profile selection

Tags: iphone, selection, profile, provisioning

I have two Team provisioning profiles which I need.
The automatic selection picks the wrong one for me at the moment.
I can't force it to use a specific one, because that choice gets submitted to svn.
Is there a way to influence the automatic selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defaults are chosen based on the bundle identifiers associated with each profile. You might think that the selector would choose the most specific identifier which matches your project, but this is not the case.

The selector chooses any profile which matches your project, with a preference for the most distant expiry date. The selection can therefore be shifted by generating your profiles in a specific order. The most recently generated profile will have a slightly later expiration date, and will therefore be preferred over older matching profiles.

(paraphrased from [retrodreamer](http://retrodreamer.com/blog/2010/08/getting-there/))

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that XCode picks the Team Provisioning Profile that was last added.
So, When you need to change the default picked profile, just reinstall it on your machine.

Comment: The selection is based on more than just the date you added the profile (see my answer below for details)